# Builds failing after upgrade to Sonar 6.7.3 from 5.6 by asking sonar.java.binaries property

Tags: sonarqube

I have upgraded to sonar 6.7.3 from 5.6, my maven project Jenkin builds are failing with below error.

> [INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project project1: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property

is it mandatory to specify sonar.java.binaries property with sonar 6.7.3 even with maven projects.

Currently we are using below plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Did you try to use the latest version (`3.4.0.905`) of the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a requirement set by the SonarQube version but by the SonarJava plugin (which likely got updated with your upgrade to 6.7).

Since SonarJava 4.12 they require you to supply the binaries as without them the plugin will miss quite some issues. As your using the Maven plugin it *will* be handled for you. I'd advise upgrading to the latest sonar-maven-plugin version as it contains several improvements.

Please check you're:

- Not overriding the sonar.java.binaries properties in your maven properties tag(s)
- Ensure the compiled sources are available (for ex. `mvn package sonar:sonar`)